# How can I keep using older versions of Skype?

Tags: mac, skype

Skype [discontinued support for older versions](http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/20/skype-announces-plan-to-discontinue-support-for-older-versions-of-mac-client/) of their Mac desktop software. This morning, my desktop software stopped letting me log in and forced me to upgrade.

But I'm relying on a previous version because it's the only one that's compatible with CamTwist.

Do you know how I could keep using the older version?

Comment: Skype has made server side changes that break compatibility with older versions.

Comment: Or put differently, time to look for an alternative to CamTwist.